# Подключение кодировки UTF8 как кодировки по умолчанию в winforms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2019

Можно ли каким то образом, через параметры проекта или программно, сделать UTF8 кодировкой по умолчанию? Если да, то как?

Comment: Кодировкой по умолчанию для чего?

Comment: @tym32167 чтобы при считывании данных, текст на русском в полях программы  выводился нормально. Если конкретнее, при считывании файлов и их записи в richTextBox и отображении их имён в treeView.

Comment: Так вы при записи / считывании указывайте нужную вам кодировку

Comment: @tym32167 Это понятно, но вопрос был в том, можно ли сделать так, чтобы это дело каждый раз не прописывать, а компутер сам понимал, в какой кодировке нужно делать запись / считывание

Comment: У компутера нет сознания, он не может ничего понимать, он делает только то и только так, как ему указали. Выделите ваши операции записи и чтения строк в отдельный класс, укажите там один раз что вам надо и забудьте о проблеме навсегда.

Comment: См. [Encoding.Default](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.default?view=net-5.0) - в .NET Core это UTF-8 по умолчанию. / Учитывая метку WinForms, полагаю, вы используете .NET FW - в этом случае всегда указывайте кодировку явно. PS: переходите на .NET 6.

Comment: Для файловых операций и так utf-8 всегда по умолчанию. И да, .NET Framework 4.x устарел.